# need help in Varnish tuning

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, centos, varnish

I am using Varnish for caching along with Apache. The CMS used is Wordpress.  Initially the load time is good. It is decreasing consequently after 5-10 minutes. Restarting varnish again reduces the loadtime. But It is not a solution. I am pasting my VCL file below. I just copied and pasted it with some edits on my varnsh

Please check and let me know whether I am doing it right. Expecting some tweaks to improve load time.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/838dc4cb576980f2902e

I have hidden the IP for some reasons.

Comment: As you mentioned load time decreases, can you confirm if it's because of varnish or is it because of other processes choking the server to respond back to customer.